# Subtract Operator in Stored Proc for Concatenate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am getting the data type error in my stored procedure because I'm using `Field1+'-'+Field2`. I tried a convert and a cast, but it's not liking the syntax I used for that pesky -.

For the subtraction operation, what's the best way to use it as a hyphen or dash instead of an operator?

Thank you!!!

Comment: What version of SQL Server? What are the datatypes of `Field1` and `Field2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert both field to strings, like this:

```
Convert(VarChar(10), Field1) + '-' + Convert(VarChar(10), Field2)
```

If either field is a number, sql server will treat this as a math operation instead of concatenation.

** I used varchar(10) as an example.  You should double check your data types and adjust the 10 accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on 2012+

```
CONCAT(Field1,'-',Field2)
```

is a bit less verbose. [Docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)

> All arguments are implicitly converted to string types and then
>   concatenated. Null values are implicitly converted to an empty string